# Не работает, а почему не понятно

Tags: javascript, html

[html............................](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FHYMg.png)

[image: js..................]

Comment: https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/12120/189027

Comment: Когда непонятно - используют отладку (см. в дубликате)